# Spring Ldap - how to implement LdapAuthoritiesPopulator

Tags: jakarta-ee, spring-security, spring-ldap

I'm developing a j2ee web page login system which reads user & role information from ldap server. For authentication, I'm using binding authentication with simple pattern matching. As for authorities, because the ldap schema and directory is rather complex, i decided i need to implement LdapAuthoritiesPopulator. but i am quite lost here and was hoping someone can point me to the right direction.

Below are some of the content in applicationContext-securityBeans.xml from the sample spring bean configuration. if i understand correctly, i need to modify the following(it's a snippet portion from applicationContext-securityBeans.xml) but i dunno how to:

```
<constructor-arg>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.DefaultAuthoritiesPopulator">
                <constructor-arg ref="contextSource" />
                <constructor-arg value="ou=Roles" />
                <property name="groupRoleAttribute" value="ou" />
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
```

i've also implemented a customAuthoritiesPopulator.java but i am not sure how to get it inserted.

here are my sample codes and i hope i will be clear regarding my problems:
web.xml

```
<context-param>
 <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
 <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext-securityBeans.xml</param-value>
```

applicationContext-securityBeans.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" access-denied-page="/user/denied" >
        <security:form-login
                login-page="/login" 
                authentication-failure-url="/login?error=true" 
                default-target-url="/admin/user"/>
        <security:logout invalidate-session="true" 
                logout-success-url="/login" 
                logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout"/>
    </security:http>
    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:ldap-authentication-provider user-dn-pattern="uid={0},ou=Users" />
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <bean id="contextSource" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource">
        <constructor-arg value="ldap://20.6.1.27:389/dc=openLDAP" />
        <property name="userDn" value="cn=admin,dc=openLDAP" />
        <property name="password" value="password" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="ldapAuthProvider" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider">
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator">
                <constructor-arg ref="contextSource" />
                <property name="userDnPatterns">
                    <list>
                        <value>uid={0},ou=Users</value>
                    </list>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>

        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.DefaultAuthoritiesPopulator">
                <constructor-arg ref="contextSource" />
                <constructor-arg value="ou=Roles" />
                <property name="groupRoleAttribute" value="ou" />
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>

    </bean>
</beans>
```

CustomAuthoritiesPopulator.java

```
package org.example.impl;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.ldap.core.DirContextOperations;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.LdapAuthoritiesPopulator;

public class CustomAuthoritiesPopulator implements LdapAuthoritiesPopulator {

    @Override
    public List<GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities(
            DirContextOperations aUserData,
            String aUsername) {
        System.out.println("in getGrantedAuthorities");
        List<GrantedAuthority> userPermission = new ArrayList<>();


        return userPermission;
    }

}
```

=======================================================================

## Edited

Ldap Structure:

```
DIT
 |
 |--Root DSE
        |
        |--dc=apacheLDAP
        |         |
        |         |--ou=Rights
        |         |     |
        |         |     |--right=1
        |         |     |--right=2
        |         |     |--right=3
        |         |--ou=Roles
        |         |     |
        |         |     |--role=1
        |         |     |--role=2
        |         |     |--role=3
        |         |     |--role=4 
        |         |
        |         |--ou=Users
        |         |     |
        |         |     |--user=ali
        |         |     |--user=john
        |         |     |--user=bettyboop
        |
        |--ou=system
               |
               |uid=admin
```

assume right 1=admin, right 2=user and right 3=guest
assume role 1=itpeople, role 2=hr, role 3=sales, role 4=ceo
assume right 1 is assigned to role 1 and role 4,  right 2 to role 2, right 3 to role 3

a right can be assigned to each role. if a role has right 1, and this role is assigned to a user, this user will have administrative rights.

when a user login, i wanna retrieve the role this user belongs to, and the right he has.

when the user navigates the web page, i will validate access to the page by checking his role and rights.

i will also check for his rights to allow him to submit post or to view certain content in a page. so for instance, a user with role 3 that has right 3(guest) will only be able to view certain content. he cannot submit a post,etc. he is even restricted in viewing certain pages.

Comment: i further elaborate how the relationship between role and right

Answer (score 0):

Going with what you have above, if all you want to do is just replace the second `constructor-arg` (currently containing a `DefaultAuthoritiesPopulator`) with;

```
<constructor-arg>
    <bean class="org.example.CustomAuthoritiesPopulator" />
</constructor-arg>
```

If you need an explanantion of how to write the class (your questions seems to imply you've already done so), you'll need to provide more details of the directory structure you're accessing.

Comment: hi, i have added the ldap structure for clarity. by the way, i have implemented the CustomAuthoritiesPopulator class but it is not being called. Do i need to add the line <constructor-arg ref="contextSource" /> below <bean class="org.example.CustomAuthoritiesPopulator" /> ???

Comment: hi luke i just realised you are the the author of spring ldapDefultAuthoritiesPopulator at here : http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/2.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/ldap/populator/DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator.html =)